# Component Tabs in react-bootstrap. Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ufa6nq

Trying to run the component `Tabs react-bootstrap` on Stackblitz, but I have error:

> Error in /turbo_modules/react-dom@16.9.0/cjs/react-dom.development.js
>   (24036:34) Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
>   it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: hi, try removing ```<Sonnet />``` components in your ```Tab``` components , because ```<Sonnet />``` is not part of ```react-bootstrap``` exists only for demo purpose